# Normalization Formula - Using Whole/Train Dataset To Calculate Mean and STD Within Formula?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, normalization

The formula to Standadize dataset is as below:

Standardzied_X = (X - Mean)/(Standard Deviation)

I was wondering if I am supposed to find mean and std on the whole dataset (concatenation of train and test) or only on train dataset. I read somewhere mean and STD of train dataset should be used in normalization formula for both train and test dataset, but it doesnt make sense to me.

Assuming data is in variables Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte with shapes [n,d], [n,1], [m,d], [m,1] respectively.

**My answer is as below :**

```
X_mean = numpy.mean(numpy.concatenate(X_tr , X_te))

X_std = numpy.std(numpy.concatenate(X_tr , X_te))

X_tr_norm = (X_tr - X_mean)/X_std

X_te_norm = (X_te - X_mean)/X_std
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programing as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Other than that, a good rule of thumb is: **pretend the test set is not available while you are building the model**; and if is not available, you cannot include it in the normalization process, right? Otherwise, does including a nonexistent part of the dataset make sense to you? Test set is there to emulate *future unseen* data...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> mean and STD of train dataset should be used in normalization formula for both train and test dataset, but it doesnt make sense to me

It makes sense to me. Firstly, train dataset should be big enough to provide good estimation of mean and std. And secondly, in such a way you do not "cheat" by using test data during training.

If you really want to calculate mean of both train and test data you do not have to concatenate them. You can calculate weighted mean and std yourself.

```
combined_mean = (len(train_data) * train_data.mean() + len(test_data) * test_data.mean()) \
                / (len(train_data) + len(test_data))
# std is more tricky
train_second_moment = np.mean((train_data - combined_mean) ** 2)
test_second_moment = np.mean((test_data - combined_mean) ** 2)
combined_std = np.sqrt((len(train_data) * train_second_moment + len(test_data) * test_second_moment) \
               / (len(train_data) + len(test_data)))
```

Comment: So, even in normalization process, we are not supposed to use "test" dataset, as it would effect the prediction ("cheating"). Interesting.

Comment: In Kaggle competitions I would even advertise to do it, but in real life its better not to use test data in any way. Anyway, I guess in most cases (when train and test data are from the same distribution) using test data to calculate mean/std would change little.